# Kuberneties Oprator metrics endpoint authentication RBAC

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-operator

I am trying to configure the metrics endpoint in a Kubernetes (k8s) operator. The comments regarding authentication are as follows:

```golang
// WithAuthenticationAndAuthorization provides a metrics.Filter for authentication and authorization.
// Metrics will be authenticated (via TokenReviews) and authorized (via SubjectAccessReviews) with the
// kube-apiserver.
// For the authentication and authorization, the controller needs a ClusterRole
// with the following rules:
// * apiGroups: authentication.k8s.io, resources: tokenreviews, verbs: create
// * apiGroups: authorization.k8s.io, resources: subjectaccessreviews, verbs: create
//
// To scrape metrics e.g. via Prometheus, the client needs a ClusterRole
// with the following rule:
// * nonResourceURLs: "/metrics", verbs: get
//
// Note: Please note that configuring this metrics provider will introduce a dependency on "k8s.io/apiserver"
// to your go module.
func WithAuthenticationAndAuthorization(config *rest.Config, httpClient *http.Client) (metricsserver.Filter, error)
```

When I connect to the metrics endpoint, it asks me for a username and password. I would appreciate help in explaining what I need to create in terms of RBAC so that I can authenticate to this endpoint.

[WithAuthenticationAndAuthorization code](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/controller-runtime/blob/main/pkg/metrics/filters/filters.go#L21)

example:
[image]

Thanks